# no instance of overloaded function "strchr" matches argument list

Tags: c++

I have to write a code that counts how many words there are in a sentence and that returns the words which have either both the first and last letters vowels or consonants. The words are each separated with a space
I get the error in the title whenever I build and run the code.

The input is " La bacalaureat la proba de Informatica a fost un subiect cu un sir de caractere "
and it is supposed to show:

15

bacalaureat Informatica a fost subiect sir

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
char b[202][202], s[101], *p;
int i, nr, ok, k;
int main ()
{
  cin.get (s, 101);
  p = strtok (s, " ");
  while (p)
    {
      strcpy (b[++k], p);
      p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
  nr = 0;
  ok = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
      nr++;
      if (b[i] != " " && (b[i + 1] == " " || b[i - 1] == " "))
    if (strchr ("aeiouAEIOU", b[i]) || !strchr ("aeiouAEIOU", b[i]))
      ok = 1;
    }
  cout << nr;
  cout << endl;
  if (ok == 1)
    cout << b[i] << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The declaration for `std::strchr` is `char *strchr( const char *str, int ch );`. You are calling it with arguments of type `const char*` and `char[]`. The latter decays to `char*` and is not implicitly convertible to `int`.

Comment: Make sure that you're providing a [example], first by hard coding the input into the program.

Comment: so am i supposed to call something like ```strchr("aeiouAEIOU", b[i][j])``` ?

Comment: That would be a valid call to `strchr`. It's not clear what you're trying to do, so I don't know if it makes algorithmic sense. Other red flags are the comparisons `b[i] != " "` etc. This isn't how you compare C-style strings.

Comment: i am trying to find out if the first and last letters of a word are vowels or consonants, so i was trying to see if the character b[i] is not space and if the preceding and following characters are spaces, and if that is true, then see if it's a vowel, and if it is, then ```ok=1``` checks that the condition is true, and at the end ```if (ok == 1)
    cout << b[i] << " ";``` if the condition is still true after the for loop, it outputs the words required

Comment: "if the character b[i] is not space" - the fundamental problem here is that `b[i]` is not a character at all. It's an array of characters in which you are storing a C-style string. Other problems: (1) `std::strtok` breaks the string into substrings based on the provided delimiter, which is `" "` in your case. It skips the delimiters themselves, so none of your `b[i]` strings will be `" "`. (2) the `cout` on the second-to-last line is printing `b[i]`, which will always be `b[k+1]` since you never exit the `for` loop early. But you haven't written anything to `b[k+1]`, so you'll print garbage.

Comment: You also never wrote anything to `b[0]`, so your use of `b[i-1]` in the `for` loop will be problematic in the first iteration when `i == 1`. Unfortunately there's too much wrong here to address suitably in a stackoverflow Q/A format.

Comment: This code would be much simpler if it used C++ features rather than C string manipulations. To read input fields separated by whitespace all you need to do is read them: `std::string word; while (std::cin >> word) { /* do something with the word */ }`. That's because `std::cin >> word` discards leading whitespace and then copies characters up to but not including the next occurrence of whitespace. Repeat until done.